# how to implement join using LINQ and EntityFramework in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4

```
> SELECT fhr_Request.RequestID, fhr_DepartmentOwners.EmpCode FROM
> fhr_Request INNER JOIN fhr_DepartmentOwners ON
> fhr_Request.[Function]=fhr_DepartmentOwners.FunctionID
```

I want to used it in linq but unable to use it, kindly suggest me how to use

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Stored Procedure to interact with the database anyway? Instead of querying the DB directly.
On the topic, you can just use "JOIN" in LINQ.

Comment: It's 2014 - why would you use a stored procedure?

Comment: @Yodoom For the sake of maintenance at least (not going to start an argument here)

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = from t1 in fhr_Request
          join t2 in fhr_DepartmentOwners
          on t1.Function equals t2.FunctionID 
          select new (fhr_Request=t1,fhr_DepartmentOwners=t2)
```